# XamlParseException due System.Core on own VSTemplate (VS2010)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, silverlight, reference, visual-studio-templates

Good noon, dear community.

I got the exercise to build a VSTemplate containing 2 projects, a web project and a silverlight project.

Solution VSTemplate:

```
<VSTemplate Version="2.0.0" Type="ProjectGroup" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005">
<TemplateData>[...]</TemplateData>
<TemplateContent>
    <ProjectCollection>
        <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$safeprojectname$_ClientSite">
            ClientSite\MyTemplate.vstemplate
        </ProjectTemplateLink>
        <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$safeprojectname$_Client">
            Client\MyTemplate.vstemplate
        </ProjectTemplateLink>
    </ProjectCollection>
</TemplateContent>
```

Silverlight-Project VSTemplate:

```
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="Project">
<TemplateContent>
    <Project TargetFileName="$safeprojectname$.csproj" File="Uettingen_Client.csproj" ReplaceParameters="true">
        <Folder Name="dlls" TargetFolderName="dlls">
            <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="false" TargetFileName="HST.Visualization.Controls.Silverlight.dll">HST.Visualization.Controls.Silverlight.dll</ProjectItem>
            [...]
        </Folder>
        <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="App.xaml">App.xaml</ProjectItem>
        <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="App.xaml.cs">App.xaml.cs</ProjectItem>
        <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="GlobalResources.xaml">GlobalResources.xaml</ProjectItem>
        <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="Head.xaml">Head.xaml</ProjectItem>
        [...]
        <Folder Name="Properties" TargetFolderName="Properties">
            <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="AppManifest.xml">AppManifest.xml</ProjectItem>
            <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="AssemblyInfo.cs">AssemblyInfo.cs</ProjectItem>
        </Folder>
        <Folder Name="Service References" TargetFolderName="Service References">
            <Folder Name="SLAuthenticationServiceReference" TargetFolderName="SLAuthenticationServiceReference">
                <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="configuration.svcinfo">configuration.svcinfo</ProjectItem>
                <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="configuration91.svcinfo">configuration91.svcinfo</ProjectItem>
                [...]
            </Folder>
        </Folder>
        <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="ServiceReferences.ClientConfig">ServiceReferences.ClientConfig</ProjectItem>
        [...]
    </Project>
</TemplateContent>
```

Silverlight project file:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="4.0">
    [...]
    <ItemGroup>
        [...]
        <Reference Include="mscorlib" />
        <Reference Include="system" />
        <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.Composition, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
        <Reference Include="System.Core" />
        <Reference Include="System.Net" />
        [...]
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Compile Include="App.xaml.cs">
            <DependentUpon>App.xaml</DependentUpon>
        </Compile>
        <Compile Include="Page1.xaml.cs">
            <DependentUpon>Page1.xaml</DependentUpon>
        </Compile>
        [...]
        <None Include="Properties\AppManifest.xml" />
        <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
        <None Include="Service References\SLAuthenticationServiceReference\configuration.svcinfo" />
        <None Include="Service References\SLAuthenticationServiceReference\configuration91.svcinfo" />
    [...]
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <ApplicationDefinition Include="App.xaml">
            <SubType>Designer</SubType>
            <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
        </ApplicationDefinition>
        <Page Include="Page1.xaml">
            <SubType>Designer</SubType>
            <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
        </Page>
        [...]
        <WCFMetadata Include="Service References\" />
        <WCFMetadataStorage Include="Service References\SLAuthenticationServiceReference\" />
        <Content Include="ServiceReferences.ClientConfig" />
        <Page Include="SplashWindow.xaml">
            <SubType>Designer</SubType>
            <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
        </Page>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Folder Include="img\" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\Silverlight\$(SilverlightVersion)\Microsoft.Silverlight.CSharp.targets" />
        <ProjectExtensions>
        <VisualStudio xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
            <FlavorProperties GUID="{A1591282-1198-4647-A2B1-27E5FF5F6F3B}">
                <SilverlightProjectProperties />
            </FlavorProperties>
            <UserProperties VisiWinNETProductType="VisiWin7" VisiWinNETRuntimeType="Standard" VisiWinNETVersion="7.0" VisiWinNETProjectName="$safeprojectname$" />
        </VisualStudio>
    </ProjectExtensions>
</Project>
```

I shorted this, as simple as it is, it works (almost) perfect. There is a problem with the System.Core:

Once i compile the generated project it throws an exeption on `InitializeComponents();` in the constructor of `App` in App.xaml.cs:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException:  [Line: 0 Position: 0] ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Now I was checking the System.Core and i realized something weird:

- The handmade project works fine of course. Just not the generated profile.
- The built was successful, this is a run time error.
- The System.Core of my generated solution is available, there is no error before compiling.
- Once I remove the System.Core, I cannot re-add it (Visual Studio does not show any message, it simply does not add it.
- It does not help to restart Visual Studio nor the whole OS. Not even adding my System.Core manually worked after this on the generated project.
- I tried to provide my template / generated projects the required System.Core locally, the problem equals exactly the same.
- I tried to clean all and rebuild it
- I tried to put `<Reference Include="System.Core, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />` or `<Reference Include="System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />` in the Uettingen_Client.csproj instead of `<Reference Include="System.Core" />`, the 4.0.0.0 part will miss the source
- I tried to remove the reference entry in the csproj and inserted `<References><Reference><Assembly>System.Core, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</Assembly></Reference></References>` or `<References><Reference><Assembly>System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</Assembly></Reference></References>` into the TemplateContent part of the project VSTemplate file. This does not work at all, the System.Core was not even shown as entry.
- I was comparing the generated silverlight project with the handmade project (I converted into a template before) by using WinMerge. Except for some formatting like spaces and except for the service reference the projects seems to match.
- If I try to add 4.0.0.0 there are conflict warnings.
- On the top example I do not get any error after clearing, building and running sometimes, however the silverlight element is complete white.

Any ideas?